# how to use UITextField.delegate textFieldDidEndEditing in rxSwift 4.0

Tags: swift, textfield, rx-swift

```
   _ = textField.rx.text.orEmpty.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
       text.count > 12
        return true
    }).subscribe(onNext: { (text) in
        let tempText:String = text
        self.textField.text = (tempText as NSString).substring(to: 12)
    })
```

it has someBug,i need use textFieldDidEndEditing

Comment: i need other delegate func ,so controlEvent is not enough

Comment: see this for help http://test.www.cocoachina.com/bbs/read.php?tid-1717107-page-e-fpage-4.html

Comment: you want didEndEditing delegate method right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use delegate proxy pattern in RxSwift.
First we need to set delegate UITextField to DelegateProxyType

```
 class RxTextFieldDelegateProxy: DelegateProxy<UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate>, DelegateProxyType, UITextFieldDelegate {

   init(textField: UITextField) {
      super.init(parentObject: textField, delegateProxy: RxTextFieldDelegateProxy.self)
   }

   static func registerKnownImplementations() {
      self.register { RxTextFieldDelegateProxy(textField: $0)}
   }

   static func currentDelegate(for object: UITextField) -> UITextFieldDelegate? {
      return object.delegate
   }

   static func setCurrentDelegate(_ delegate: UITextFieldDelegate?, to object: UITextField) {
         object.delegate = delegate
      }
}
```

Second we can define properties by ourself in RxSwift.

```
extension Reactive where Base: UITextField {

   public var delegate: DelegateProxy<UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate> {
      return RxTextFieldDelegateProxy.proxy(for: base)
   }

   public var editingDidEnd: Observable<String> {
      return delegate.sentMessage(#selector(UITextFieldDelegate.textFieldDidEndEditing(_:))).map { value in
         guard let textField = value[0] as? UITextField else { return "" }
         return textField.text!   }
   }

}
```

Third usage:

```
myTextField.rx.editingDidEnd.subscribe(onNext: { value in
         debugPrint(value)
      }).disposed(by: bag)
```

Answer (score 2):

**RxSwift 4.0**

If you want to user `UITextField` delegate method you have use `controlEvent.

```
var bag = DisposeBag()
```

Now put observer in `viewDidLoad` method.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        controls.txtTitle.rx
            .controlEvent([.editingDidEnd])
            .asObservable()
            .subscribe(onNext: {
                print("Editing done")
            }).disposed(by: bag)
    }
```

Comment: the suggested answers takes advantage of controlEvent witch is of type UIControl.Event, not of type UITextFieldDelegate. By using controlEvent one can not take advantage of textFieldShouldBeginEditing and other similar delegate methods..